# Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalRelease'. > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration

Tags: flutter, gradle

Guys getting this error i dont know what is my mistake and why this is not working ?

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not resolve org.jfrog.cardinalcommerce.gradle:cardinalmobilesdk:2.2.1-2.
> Required by:
> project :app > project :braintree_payment > com.braintreepayments.api:drop-in:4.5.0 > com.braintreepayments.api:three-d-secure:3.7.2
> > Skipped due to earlier error
> > Skipped due to earlier error

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 0s